# Can Windows Server 2012 R2 mount a NFS 4.1 target?

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2, nfs4

We're looking at the new AWS feature Elastic File System (EFS). One of the caveats is that Windows Server EC2 instances are not supported (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/gs-step-one-create-ec2-resources.html) This appears to be linked to the fact that EFS utilises NFS v4.1, and Windows server will not support this.

However, the official Windows Server 2012 R2 documentation states that it will support NFS server/client v4.1 (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574143(v=ws.11).aspx)

If this is the case then Windows Server 2012 R2 **can** mount an EFS v4.1 target, and mention of Windows not being supported are unfounded. It's not clear though, if anyone could answer definitively that would be appreciated.

Comment: Whether Windows Server 2012 R2 supports NFS v4.1 targets (it does) is a different question from whether or not Amazon EC2 instances running Windows Server 2012 R2 support Amazon's EFS.  Why not spin up an instance and check for yourself?

Comment: Perhaps, but can't understand why it would be different, as you're simply natively mounting a target from within Windows Server 2012 R2. Think the downvote a tad harsh as I'm sure plenty of people will be interested in the outcome, and I feel it's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 5):

This is not supported scenario (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html), no need to check. And I think this is artificial or political limitation.

Comment: Not supported does not mean does not work.  That said, there seems to be something that prevents it from working. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956130/aws-efs-from-windows-server-2012?answertab=active#tab-top that seems to answer the question of why.

Comment: For this to work, you need a NFS 4.1 client on the windows server. The shipped NFS client in windows is not v4.1 compatible.